Got undefined param value in a generated element in antd Tabs -> TabPane
I would like to create a customized TabPane for an Antd tab,
The Tabs definition:
      <Tabs>
        {myTab.map((tab) => (
          <TabPane tab={tab.label} key={tab.label}>
            {tab.children}
          </TabPane>
        ))}
      </Tabs>

The myTab definition:
  const myTab = Object.keys(target.data).map((targetKey) => {
    let hierarchy = [];
    hierarchy = target.hierarchy.filter((i) => i.key === targetKey)[0].children;
    let modeInfo =  {};
    modeInfo = target.data[targetKey];
    return {
      label: targetKey,
      key: targetKey,
      children: (
        <>
          <InfoPage modeInfo={modeInfo} hierarchy={hierarchy} selectedTarget={targetKey}/>
        </>
      ),
    };
  });

The data structure of target looks something like this:
{
   data: {
      XXXXX : {....}
   }
   hierarchy : [ 
      {
         children: [...]
         key: 'XXXXX'
      }
   ]
}

The InfoPage js
const InfoPage = ( modeInfo, hierarchy, selectedTarget) =>
{
    .....
    const renderTree = (**hierarchy**) => {
       if (Array.isArray(**hierarchy**)) {
         return hierarchy.map(({ key, children }) => {
           return renderTarget(key, children);
          });
       } else {
         console.error('hierarchy is not an array') 
       return [];
      }
    };

    const renderTarget = (key, checks) => {
    return {
      ...updatedInfo[selectedKey][Key],
      children: checks.map((check) => renderCheck(check.key, check.children)),
    };
  };
    return (
      <>
       <Card title={<Title/>} style={{ borderWidth: '2px', borderRadius: '10px' }}>
        <Tree
          checkable
          //checkStrictly
          onExpand={onExpand}
          expandedKeys={expandedKeys}
          autoExpandParent={autoExpandParent}
          //onCheck={onCheck}
          checkedKeys={checkedKeys}
          selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
          multiple
          treeData={renderTree(**hierarchy**)}
          blockNode={true}
        />
      </Card>
      </>
}

Got error in the const renderTree, hierarchy is 'undefined'
I can get the data of 'modeInfo' & 'hierarchy' at the root level when initialize the InfoPage element, how ever I keep getting 'undefined' for all the input params within InfoPage.

Can you post your InfoPage code, since that's the problem area?

updated with InfoPage.js

Looks like you are missing curly braces when destructuring the props in InfoPage component.
const InfoPage = ( modeInfo, hierarchy, selectedTarget) =>


should be
const InfoPage = ({modeInfo, hierarchy, selectedTarget}) =>

